# How to create a temp boolean field with Django orm

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models

Image I have following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Receipt(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have an input list of product ids and a user. I want to query for each product, whether it's been purchased by this user. Notice I need a queryset with all exist products based on given input because there are other fields I need for each product even not purchased by this user, so I cannot use `Product.objects.filter(receipt__user=user)`.

So can I create a temp Boolean field to present this property in one single query? I am using Django 1.8 and postgresql 9.3

Update requirements:To separate products into two groups. One is bought by this specific user, the other one is not. I don't think any given filter can implement this. This should be implement by creating a new temp field either by annotate or F expression.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What property would you like to filter by?

Comment: @Mint To separate products into two groups. One is bought by this specif user, the other one is not. I don't think any given filter can implement this. This should be implement by creating a new temp field either by annotate or F expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you need **`.annotate()`** expression as

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Case, When, Value

product_queryset = Product.objects.annotate(
    is_purchased=Case(
        When(receipt__user=current_user, then=Value('True')),
        default=Value('False')

    ))
```

How to access the annotated field?

```
product_queryset.first().is_purchased
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for @JPG's answer.

I just realize except conditional expressions, there's another easy way to do it.

Just using prefetch_related will implement everything in two queries. Although it's double than conditional expressions, but it's still a considerable time complexity solution.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3,4,5]).prefetch_related ('receipt_set').all()
```

Then we can detect user for this product in Python by

```
for p in products:
    print user in [receipt.user_id for receipt in p.purchase_set.all()]
```